# Const variable declaration

Tags: c++, constants, correctness

I have a function returning a const reference to an object as follows:

```
const &Foo getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

If I have another function as follows:

```
void bar() {
    const qwerty = asdf.getFoo();
    int x = qwerty.x + 5;
    // something here
}
```

Is preceding qwerty with const necessary or best practice?

Comment: Did the compiler complain when you removed the const?

Comment: Necessary: Try it and the compiler will tell you. Best practice: Primarilly opinion based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all, it's neither necessary nor best practice - it's insufficient. You need a type too. Once you fill that in, the `const` is still not necessary, unless you try to take it by non-`const` reference. We have three choices that could compile:

```
Foo qwerty =  asdf.getFoo();       // (A)
const Foo qwerty = asdf.getFoo();  // (B)
const Foo& qwerty = asdf.getFoo(); // (C)
```

Given that `getFoo()` returns a reference to `const`, the most efficient thing would be to take it as reference to `const` as well, that avoids a copy. Unless, that is, you *want* a copy - in which case do `(A)` or `(B)`, depending on whether or not you want a modifiable copy or not. Unless `Foo` is non-copyable, in which case `(C)` is your only option anyway.

Ultimately, it depends on what you want to do with `qwerty`. I would default to `(C)`, and need a reason to pick one or the other instead.